# Convertion from CSV to JSON in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I'm facing difficulty while converting CSV to JSON.Below is the code  which I'm trying to convert

```
d3.csv("http://localhost:8080/Sample/flight.csv", function(flights) {           
                //alert(flights);
              var linksByOrigin = {},
                  countByAirport = {},
                  locationByAirport = {},
                  positions = [];

              var arc = d3.geo.greatArc()
              .source(function(d) { return locationByAirport[d.source]; })
              .target(function(d) { return locationByAirport[d.target]; }); 

              //reading from csv
                flights.forEach(function(flight) {
                var origin = flight.origin,
                    destination = flight.destination,
                    links = linksByOrigin[origin] || (linksByOrigin[origin] = []);
                links.push({source: origin, target: destination});
                countByAirport[origin] = (countByAirport[origin] || 0) + 1;
                countByAirport[destination] = (countByAirport[destination] || 0) + 1;
              });
```

});

to

```
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/Sample/flight.json", function(flights) {             
                //alert(flights);
              var linksByOrigin = {},
                  countByAirport = {},
                  locationByAirport = {},
                  positions = [];

              var arc = d3.geo.greatArc()
              .source(function(d) { return locationByAirport[d.source]; })
              .target(function(d) { return locationByAirport[d.target]; }); 

              var flights = flights.flights;
              alert("flights"+flights.length);
           for(var i = 0; i < flights.length; i++)    {    
               alert("origin"+flights[i].origin+"dest"+flights[i].destination);
                 var origin = flights[i].origin;
            var  destination = flights[i].destination;
          alert("origin"+origin+"dest"+destination)
                var links = linksByOrigin[origin] || (linksByOrigin[origin] = []);
                links.push({source: origin , target: destination});
                countByAirport[origin] = (countByAirport[origin] || 0) + 1;
                countByAirport[destination] = (countByAirport[destination] || 0) + 1;   
           }
});
```

It is giving me `19:15:41.950 TypeError: _ is undefined1 d3.v2.js:1982:10`
 whe i'm using the json code.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong while converting.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your json object for more information, but based on the following assumption, that your csv was returning an array of objects:

```
[{origin: 'origin string', destination: 'destination string'} ... ]
```

And if your json is stored as follows:

```
{flights: [{origin: 'origin string', destination: 'destination string'}, ...]}
```

Then your code should work. If your json is of a different format, if you could upload a sample csv, and json files, i could give you a better answer.

Its hard to say whats wrong with just that error, but my guess would be you do not have a flights variable set in your json file.

Comment: here my flights json - `{"flights":[{"origin":"6972475","destination":"1411474","count":"1853"},
{"origin":"6972475","destination":"4683455","count":"2853"}
]}` and my flights csv `origin,destination,count
6972475,1411474,2853
6972475,4683455,1853`

Comment: It is working now.Need to be very careful while building the json.Mistake I have done is that I have left a space  .Instead of `"destination":"1411474"` it was like `"destination":"1411474 "`. Thats why is was throwing error.

Comment: Great you managed to figure it out! Wouldnt be able to find that here without the complete json and code.